# Wordpress address url option missing under general setting

Tags: url-rewriting

Anyone can help me out ?

Why don't I see 'wordpress address url' and 'site address url' under general setting in order to change url. like below image :  Thanks in advance. [image]

Comment: Is your site part of a MultiSite? If it's a subsite, you would not have any options to set URLs.

Comment: Thanks. It's multisite. but I'm trying with main site general setting. is there any other reason?

Comment: I'm surprised they're not displayed there for multisites even if they're not editable.

Answer (score 0):

You have the following in your wp-config.php...remove them and you will see the options in the admin.

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

Comment: even after remove those code from wp-config.php file it's still remain same!

Comment: hmmm.  Are you sure you uploaded the file?  :)  

Assuming you wanted to change the admin setting, you could leave the above in your config file and make the change there, it does the same thing.

Comment: I would confirm you are uploading the file properly by temporarily removing everything from the file and saving it, when you view the site now you should see an "Error Establishing Database Connection" error.  Don't forget to undo your changes to the config file and save again.

The only other thing I could think of would be to disable all your plugins and then check the admin, maybe you have a plugin causing this.